# dynamic filtering rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with > 2000 features. Categorical, numerical and logical types.

The constraint for further processing is that the Numerical features should not have any value < 0. However, these are present in the set.

I would like to now a way how to remove all examples (rows) from the underlying data set where at least one numerical feature is negative.

Already tried it this way `apply(df, 1, function(x) any(as.numeric(x) <0))`
However, this convert my categorical features to NaN.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of data (use `dput`) to enable testing of potential solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find all numerical columns:

```
df.classes <- lapply(df, class)
df.num     <- c( which(df.classes == "numeric"), which(df.classes == "integer") ) # if you also want to include integer
```

Then I'd go over `df[, df.num]` and see if there are any negative values, e.g. with `rowSums( any(df[, df.num] < 0) )`. Then discard all rows with a value for that `> 0`.

Good luck!

Comment: You are absolutely right! Well first split the data by types solve it. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

```
numeric <- df[,sapply(df,class) %in% c('numeric','integer')]
result <- numeric[!apply(numeric,1,function(x) any(x < 0)),]
```